# Problem with optional arguments in PHP

Tags: php

I have a function which takes four optional arguments:

```
public function doSomething($x = null, $y = null, $a = null, $b = null) {  }
```

However when I try to call this function and specify only $y for instance:

```
$object->doSomething($y=3)
```

It seems to ignore that I am setting $y as 3, and instead sets $x to be 3. Is there any reason why this might happen with PHP? I never used to have this issue before...

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must pass arguments in the order that you declare in your method signature, whether they're optional or not. That means you must specify `$x` before `$y`, no matter what.

If you don't need to pass any other value of `$x`, you'll have to pass null. You can still skip the remaining optional arguments, of course:

```
$object->doSomething(NULL, 3)
```

Additionally, PHP does not support named arguments. Therefore, you cannot explicitly write `$y` in the calling code because in PHP that actually sets `$y` within the scope of the calling code, and not the scope of `doSomething()`'s method body.

**EDIT:** per dpk's suggestion, as an alternative route you can change the method to accept a hash (associative array) instead, and optionally overwrite some defaults and `extract()` the values of it into scope:

```
public function doSomething(array $args = array()) {
    $defaults = array('x' => NULL, 'y' => NULL, 'a' => NULL, 'b' => NULL);
    extract(array_merge($defaults, $args));

    // Use $x et al as normal...
}
```

In your calling code:

```
$object->doSomething(array('y' => 3));
```

Comment: Right. The way to do this as the OP expects is to pass a single hash as the argument (array('y' => 3)) or some similar data structure (object..)

Comment: Thanks for that - for some reason I was under the assumption you could do what I was doing. Must have been another language creeping in!

Answer (score 1):

Even though $x is optional, the position is not so $y needs to be the second parameter.  Try:

```
$object->doSomething(null,3);
```